# Any one enplane output of the if statement?

Tags: c, if-statement

What will be output if you will compile and execute the following c statement?

```
if(printf("This is"))
  printf(" tricky question");
```

the output is
`This is tricky question`

Comment: Is it me, or is your answer already at the bottom of your question?

Comment: This question is not a question at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return type of printf function is integer which returns number of character it prints including blank spaces.
So printf function inside if condition will return 7. And print massage `This is`
In if condition any non- zero number means true so else part will not execute. And print massage `tricky question`

Answer (score 4):

The docs for [printf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) explain why this happens

> Return value
>
> Upon successful return, these functions return the number of
>   characters printed (excluding the null byte used to end output to
>   strings).

`printf("This is")` returns 7 so your `if` condition succeeds.